# Message after installing tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I have just installed `tensorflow` on `Ubuntu 16.04` for Python3.5 as it is the preinstalled Python3 version.

I installed via `pip3 install tensorflow-cpu`, i used cpu because my Ubuntu 16.04 does not recognize my GPU in my fairly new laptop but this is another issue.

So after I just tried a simple hello world program with tensorflow I got following message:

```
2020-11-01 09:36:51.577315: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

I don't really understand what this means. Do I have to build tensorflow again or can I use it for ML tasks like this? If so how can I do this correctly with appropriate compiler flags?

Best regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just ignore that informational message and carry on with your ML work.

It's just telling you that you *could* rebuild Tensorflow to maybe use more of the advanced instructions your CPU supports.